# what is the difference between Intent.Action_BATTERY_CHANGED and android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

According to my topic, actually there is no function difference between them, but my question is why system broadcasts registration like " Intent.Action_BATTERY_CHANGED" do not need double quotation marks to show as String when i dynamically register a receiver. And also, for all the action_broadcast list, there is no more detail about this "logogram", so what kinds of other system broadcasts can be represented like this? where can i find a list similar to the "Intent.Action_BATTERY_CHANGED" (kinds of abbreviation)

Answer (score 1):

> why system broadcasts registration like " Intent.Action_BATTERY_CHANGED" do not need double quotation marks to show as String when i dynamically register a receiver

`Intent` is a Java class. `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a `static` data member of that Java class. You refer to static data members directly in Java, not via quotation marks.

> where can i find a list similar to the "Intent.Action_BATTERY_CHANGED"

`Intent` is a Java class. Java classes in the Android SDK have documentation, such as [the documentation for the `Intent` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). The documentation for Java classes includes a list of `static` data members, including dozens that are prefixed with `ACTION_`.

Not all `Intent` actions defined in the Android SDK are listed on the `Intent` class, but most of them are.